Reciprocity theorem for dependent sources
I studied that reciprocity theorem is not valid for network with dependent current sources , i tried multiple ways but could not prove it . can someone help

To help get an answer can you [edit] the question to explain what you have tried, and where you are stuck.

Edit the ALL CAPS in the title, people assume you are SHOUTING at us.

What would you get for the current through R3?

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Now what would happen if you moved V1 to the R3 side? What would be the current through R1?

simulate this circuit
Would this prove that the reciprocity theorem should not be applied if the circuit has dependent sources?

One can DISprove an assertion with one counterexample. The counterexample given by Math is sufficient.
Now it is possible to construct a circuit that contains dependent sources that is reciprocal; for example a circuit that contains a dependent current source in parallel with its controlling voltage.
